# Normality is transitive along a chain of index 2 subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $G_1$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $[G:G_1]=2$. Now suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1$ with odd order. Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Some remarks/partial progress:

1. I have shown that if $G$ is a group, $G_1$ is a subgroup of index $2$, and $H$ is a subgroup of odd order, then $H\subset G_1$. I don't think this is relevant to the problem at hand though.
2. If $H$ is a group of odd order, squaring is injective.
3. Since $G_1$ in the original problem statement has index $2$, any element $g\in G$ satisfies $g^2 \in G_1$.
4. If $g\in G$ is in $G_1$, then clearly $gH=Hg$, so it suffices to show our claim for $g\in G\setminus G_1$. Note further than $G\setminus G_1$ is the set of all elements of even order.

Comment: You wrote "suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1$" and "prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1$." Please proofread carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no". Take the wreath product $G=C_3\wr C_2$ of order $18$. It has a subgroup $G_1=C_3\times C_3$ of index $2$. The subgroup $G_1$ has several subgroups $H$ of order 3, each of which is normal in the Abelian group $G_1$ but only one of which is normal in $G$.

Comment: I apologize; I intended to include in my problem that $H$ has odd order. Of course, you are absolutely right as my problem is stated. I have upvoted your answer but edited the problem to reflect my intentions.

Comment: I changed the answer. $H$ has order 9. You can replace $C_3$ by any $C_n$ with odd $n$, then the subgroup $H$ will have order $n^2$.

Comment: Which orders of $H$ are possible is a separate question. Clearly $H$ cannot be of prime order. It must have an automorphism of order 2.

Comment: Of course the simplest example is $C_2\wr C_2=D_4$, but in this case $|H|=4$.

Comment: In all these comments $H$ is what the OP calls $G_1$.